# Misunderstanding the dimension of QCD

Tags: dimensional-analysis, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills

From my point of view, the definition of the tension tensor is contradictory.
$$F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu} +ig[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}]$$
$$[A_{\mu}]=\frac{1}{cm \times g};[F_{\mu \nu}]=\frac{1}{cm^2 \times g}$$
It does not correspond to the dimensions of classical electrodynamics and contradicts another formula of the standard model.
$$\partial^{\mu} F_{\mu \nu}+ig [A^{\mu}, F_{\mu \nu}]=j_{\nu}$$
It turns out a contradiction, according to the first formula Huang K. Quarks Leptons and Gauge Field formula (3.54) $A(r)=\frac{n}{e \times r}[1-F(r)]$, the potential is inversely proportional to the charge, and according to the second formula, it is directly proportional to the charge, since the current is directly proportional to the charge.
But I am at a loss how such bloopers are possible and if I am not mistaken. Please explain the situation with the dimension of the standard model. Is the proposed standard model notation valid?

Comment: What contradiction do you think there is?

Comment: You *do* understand what setting all these constants =1 [*means*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Natural_units_(particle_and_atomic_physics))  and you are completely comfortable with this, no?

Comment: As a result of these ill-considered actions, a contradiction with the formulas arose. Direct and inverse proportionality at the same time. In the books of Landau and Lifshitz, the constants 1 are also equated, but in difficult cases the formulas are given in full. This was not done in the standard model. I have nothing against the standard model, but it must be written correctly and not lead to contradictions.

Answer (score 3):

Basically *all* of QFT is done in [natural units](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/%7Ekorytov/phz5354/note_01_NaturalUnits_SMsummary.pdf) in which the speed of light and the reduced Planck constant are set to unity, $$c=\hbar=1.$$ There is rarely any need to work in any different system $-$ you need to be doing something very specific to do so, and if that is the case you always note it explicitly. Otherwise, the default is to assume natural units.

The dimensionality content of your two formulas basically boils down to the dimensionality of $g$, which is
$$
[g] = \frac{[F]}{[A^2]} = \frac{[A/L]}{[A^2]} = [1/AL]
$$
for the first one, and
$$
[g] = \frac{[F/L]}{[FA]} = [1/AL]
$$
for the second one, so there is no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Evgeniy, I don't agree with your answer.

If you want to put in the explicit $\hbar$ and $c$ and thus work in Gaussian units rather than natural units, I believe that you should be dividing the dimensionless strong coupling constant $g$ by $\sqrt{\hbar c}$, not $\hbar c$, everywhere that it appears, so that the equations are

$$F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu} +i\frac{g}{\sqrt{\hbar c}}[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}],\tag{1}$$

$$\partial^{\mu} F_{\mu \nu}+i\frac{g}{\sqrt{\hbar c}} [A^{\mu}, F_{\mu \nu}]=j_{\nu},\tag{2}$$

$$D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+i\frac{g}{\sqrt{\hbar c}} A_{\mu}.\tag{3}$$

To check that the Gaussian dimensions work out consistently across the terms in each of the three equations, you can start from the fact that the action $S$ has dimensions of energy times time:

$$[S]=[E][T]=[M][L]^2[T]^{-1}.\tag{4}$$

The Lagrangian density in the action integral thus has the dimensions

$$[\mathcal{L}]=\frac{[S]}{[L]^3[T]}=[M][L]^{-1}[T]^{-2}.\tag{5}$$

Since the Lagrangian density has an $F^2$ term,

$$[F]=[\mathcal L]^{1/2}=[M]^{1/2}[L]^{-1/2}[T]^{-1}.\tag{6}$$

Since $F\sim\partial A$ and

$$[\partial]=[L]^{-1},\tag{7}$$

one has

$$[A]=\frac{[F]}{[\partial]}=[M]^{1/2}[L]^{1/2}[T]^{-1}.\tag{8}$$

Using

$$[\hbar]=[S]=[M][L]^2[T]^{-1}\tag{9}$$

and

$$[c]=[L][T]^{-1}\tag{10}$$

and the fact that $g$ is dimensionless, one has

$$\left[\frac{g}{\sqrt{\hbar c}}\right]=[M]^{-1/2}[L]^{-3/2}[T].\tag{11}$$

Then one finds that the dimensions of all terms in (1), (2), and (3) are consistent, with the additional conclusion that

$$[j]=[M]^{1/2}[L]^{-3/2}[T]^{-1}.\tag{12}$$

In natural units with $\hbar=c=1$, there is only one dimension, which we can take to be $[M]$, with

$$[L]=[M]^{-1}\tag{13}$$

and

$$[T]=[M]^{-1}.\tag{14}$$

Then we have

$$[S]=[1]\tag{15}$$
$$[\mathcal L]=[M]^4\tag{16}$$
$$[F]=[M]^2\tag{17}$$
$$[\partial]=[M]\tag{18}$$
$$[A]=[M]\tag{19}$$
$$[g]=[1]\tag{20}$$
$$[j]=[M]^3.\tag{21}$$

You can see how much simpler it is to think about dimensions in natural units!

Comment: I don't understand your formula (11). $[\frac{g}{\sqrt{\hbar c}}]=[\frac{g}{e}]=[\frac{1}{sin\theta_w}]$

Comment: If the coupling constant is considered as dimensionless, then you are right, if it has the dimension of charge, then I am right.  The coefficient in front of the nonlinear term in the case of calculating the strength or in front of the potential in the case of the calibration derivative must have the dimension of the reverse charge.

Comment: Why the natural units method is bad. If there is a sum of two expressions in natural units, then it cannot be used. The coefficient in front of each member of the sum is unknown and the structure of the members in the sum may be different. This is exactly what happened with the dimension of tension in this problem.

Comment: Including a dimensionless speed value in the formula will distort the calculation results. Even the equation $mu=k;\hbar=1;c=1$ for the mass is not solved correctly, since the mass is included only in the first factor and the right-hand side, and the dimensionless velocity is variable, and the value of the mass depends on the value of the velocity. With a constant mass, an increase in speed will increase the mass value.

Answer (score -2):

From my point of view, the correct formulas take into account Planck's constant and the speed of light.
$$F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu} +ig[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}]/(\hbar c)$$
$$\partial^{\mu} F_{\mu \nu}+ig [A^{\mu}, F_{\mu \nu}]/(\hbar c)=j_{\nu}$$
$$D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+ig A_{\mu}/(\hbar c)$$
Then the tensor of tension and the potential has the dimension of classical electrodynamics and the potential in the gauge derivative is proportional to the charge.
I will only cite incorrectly calculated formulas that are obtained from incorrect calculations.
The formula (3.57) from [1] $ \int_ {0} ^ {\infty} B(r)r ^ 2 dr = \frac {n} {e} $ is also not correct. It follows from the incorrect formula (3.54)
$$ A(r) = \frac{n}{er} [1 + F(r)] $$
$$ B(r) = \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} [rA(r)] = \frac {n} {er} F ^ {‘}(r) $$
The correct formula is $ \int_{0}^{\infty} B(r)r ^ 2 dr = en $, $ A(r) = \frac{en}{r} [1 + F(r)]$
$ B(r) = \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} [rA(r)] = \frac{en}{r} F ^ {‘}(r) $

The formula $ A_{\mu} = \frac {1} {er} $ is not correct, it must be replaced by the dimensional formula $ A_{\mu} = \frac {e} {r} $ and the stress and potential tensor is directly proportional to the charge.
Mixed up formulas with topological charge. Correct formula for topological charge. It is obtained in compliance with the dimension
$$ q = \frac{1}{16 \pi^2 g} \int d^4 x Tr (\overline {F}^{\mu \nu} F_ {\mu \nu}) $$
$$ A^{\mu} = - ig U \partial^{\mu} U$$
As a result, we get the formula $ q = ng $, and for the wrong formula we have $ q = n $.
Moreover, in [1] there are incorrect formulas for the stress tensor formula (5.29)
$$ F_{\mu \nu} = \frac{2}{g} \frac {\rho^2} {(\rho^2 + r^2) ^ 2} \tau_{\mu \nu} $$

Correct formulas the field is proportional to the charge $$ F_{\mu \nu} = \frac {2g \rho^2} {(\rho^2 + r^2)^2} \tau_{\mu \nu} $$
The formula for determining the mass of a particle is correct, since all quantities included in this formula are proportional.

```
                                  Literature
```

1. Huang K. Quarks, leptons and gauge fields Mir Publishing House, 1985, 382 pp.

Comment: Most QFT books are written in units where $\hbar=c=1$. If you agree with them up to factors of $\hbar,c$ then you're probably both correct.

Comment: The fact is that the result is the dimension of the potential tensor, $\frac{1}{cm \times g}$ that I object to

Comment: I approach it formally, there is a formula $A=\frac{1}{g \times r}$ for the potential and it is not correct, you cannot count from it

Comment: Writing down the standard model with $\hbar=1,c=1$ incorrect consequences obtained, which contradict the formulas of the standard model. From some formulas follows a directly proportional dependence potential on the charge, and from others inverse proportionality see the formulas of the main message.